# How can I access namespaced XML elements using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-namespaces

I have an XML document which reads like this:

```
<xml>
<web:Web>
<web:Total>4000</web:Total>
<web:Offset>0</web:Offset>
</web:Web>
</xml>
```

my question is how do I access them using a library like BeautifulSoup in python?

xmlDom.web["Web"].Total ? does not work?

Comment: Outdated since BeautifulSoup = 4.6.1 (20180728)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) isn't a DOM library per se (it doesn't implement the DOM APIs).  To make matters more complicated, you're using namespaces in that xml fragment.  To parse that specific piece of XML, you'd use BeautifulSoup as follows:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<xml>
  <web:Web>
    <web:Total>4000</web:Total>
    <web:Offset>0</web:Offset>
  </web:Web>
</xml>"""

doc = BeautifulSoup( xml )
print doc.find( 'web:total' ).string
print doc.find( 'web:offset' ).string
```

If you weren't using namespaces, the code could look like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<xml>
  <Web>
    <Total>4000</Total>
    <Offset>0</Offset>
  </Web>
</xml>"""

doc = BeautifulSoup( xml )
print doc.xml.web.total.string
print doc.xml.web.offset.string
```

The key here is that BeautifulSoup doesn't know (or care) anything about namespaces.  Thus `web:Web` is treated like a `web:web` tag instead of as a `Web` tag belonging to th e`web` namespace.  While BeautifulSoup adds `web:web` to the xml element dictionary, python syntax doesn't recognize `web:web` as a single identifier.

You can learn more about it by reading the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

Comment: thanks! works perfectly now. 

I am always getting confused as to what to give to find() ..and these namespace definitions and the way they are written confuses me a lot ...any link to clear all that up would be appreciated!

Comment: Just the documentation link I already gave you ... and lots of experimentation.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'`

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question but somebody might not know that at least [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) *does* handle namespaces well if you pass `'xml'` as second argument to the constructor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<xml>
<web:Web>
<web:Total>4000</web:Total>
<web:Offset>0</web:Offset>
</web:Web>
</xml>""", 'xml')

print soup.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
 <Web>
  <Total>
   4000
  </Total>
  <Offset>
   0
  </Offset>
 </Web>
</xml>
```

Comment: This is not exactly true for version  4.4.1-1 (in ubuntu 64 16.04). Since comments are limited. See [link](https://pastebin.com/Q99iK6tM)

Answer (score 2):

## Environment

```
import bs4
bs4.__version__
---
4.10.0'

import sys
print(sys.version)
---
3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
```

### BS4/XML Parser on XML with namespace definition

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xbrl_with_namespace = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrl
    xmlns:dei="http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2020-01-31"
>
<dei:EntityRegistrantName>
Hoge, Inc.
</dei:EntityRegistrantName>
</xbrl>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_with_namespace, 'xml')
registrant = soup.find("dei:EntityRegistrantName")
print(registrant.prettify())
---
<dei:EntityRegistrantName>
Hoge, Inc.
</dei:EntityRegistrantName>
```

### BS4/XML Parser on XML without namespace definition

```
xbrl_without_namespace = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dei:EntityRegistrantName>
Hoge, Inc.
</dei:EntityRegistrantName>
</xbrl>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_without_namespace, 'xml')
registrant = soup.find("dei:EntityRegistrantName")
print(registrant)
---
None
```

### BS4/HTML Parser on XML without namespace definition

BS4/HTML parser regards `<namespace>:<tag>` as a single tag, besides it lower the letters.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_without_namespace, 'html.parser')
registrant = soup.find("dei:EntityRegistrantName".lower()) 

print(registrant)
---
<dei:entityregistrantname>
Hoge, Inc.
</dei:entityregistrantname>
```

Does not match with capital letters as they have been converted into lower letters.

```
registrant = soup.find("dei:EntityRegistrantName") 
print(registrant)
---
None
```

## Conclusion

1. Provide the namespace definitions to use namespaces with XML parser, OR
2. Use HTML parser and handle with all small letters.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly define your namespace on root element, using `xmlns:prefix="URI"`syntax ([see examples here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)), and then you access you attribute via `prefix:tag` from BeautifulSoup. Keep in mind,what you also should explicitly define, how BeautifulSoup should process you document, in that case:

> xml = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, 'xml')

Answer (score 0):

For the examples below I’m assuming you:

1. have your namespaces declared at the top of your XML file: `xmlns:ns_name="http://example.com"`
2. have your XML parsed as xml: `BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')`

**Extracting known tags in a namespace**

If `<ns_name:tag_name>` is known, the `find()` and `find_all()` methods will work just fine - as mentioned in this thread already.

```py
# extract the first element with tag name
xml_soup.find('web:Web')

# extract all elements with tag name
xml_soup.find_all('web:Web')
```

**Searching within a namespace with CSS selectors**

BS4 also allows you to [search within namespaces using CSS selectors](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors) by using a prefix: your namespace, a pipe symbol `|` and finally your CSS selector. Template: `ns_name|css_selector`.

```py
# select all elements in the namespace 'web'
xml_soup.select('web|*')

# selecting specific elements within the namespace 'web'
xml_soup.select('web|Web > Total')
```

**More complex searches within a namespace**

For anything more complex, you’ll want to write a custom boolean function:

```py
def ns_and_regex_match(tag) -> bool:
  if tag.prefix != 'web':
    return False
  return bool(re.search('^Off.*$', tag.name))

xml_soup.find_all(ns_and_regex_match)
```