# Beautiful Soup tag has colon. Need to extract temperature Value.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to output the temperature -> **34**, but the colon in the tag (yweather:condition) is causing a syntax error

For example, this is a sample of my xml file

```
<pubDate ...> </pubDate> <yweather:condition  text="Cloudy"  code="26"  temp="34"  date="Fri, 20 Dec 2013 3:20 pm PST" /> <xml text>
```

My code so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myString)
temp = soup.yweather:condition['temp']
print temp
```

Result - Invalid Syntax

I've tried the code below, but not sure how to get the temp value from here.

```
temp = soup.find('yweather:condition')
```

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML, but your file is XML. Somwhat similar, but different. Python has several XML parsers that should parse that without problem.

Comment: bs can parse xml: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
temp = soup.find('yweather:condition')['temp']

>>> 34
```

`yweather` is a namespace, see [How can I access namespaced XML elements using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058912/how-can-i-access-namespaced-xml-elements-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: *Sometimes* using only the word after colon works well like `soup.condition`. It's worth trying.