# How to remove namespaces from MiniDom elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, minidom

I have `minidom` object which i need to save  to string, but the problem is that each element is wrapped by some name-space, is it possible to remove it? Here is my example:

```
<Device:GetDeviceInformationResponse>
    <Device:Manufacturer>Pelco</Device:Manufacturer>
    <Device:Model>D5</Device:Model>
    <Device:FirmwareVersion>1.9.2.19-201</Device:FirmwareVersion>
    <Device:SerialNumber>AC</Device:SerialNumber>
    <Device:HardwareId>7006</Device:HardwareId>
</Device:GetDeviceInformationResponse>
```

Comment: Consider this: the meaning of the XML changes if you remove the namespace. Is that indeed intended?

Comment: Similar: [How can I access namespaced XML elements using BeautifulSoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058912/how-can-i-access-namespaced-xml-elements-using-beautifulsoup)?

Comment: @SimeonVisser sorry, just edited  my question.