# find xls tag and his childs whith python

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, elementtree

I'm having some troubles to find inside a xls code file an specific tag and get it with his childs.

for exemple:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:crossFunction="http://bla.bla.bla/" xmlns:simple-date-format="xalan://java.text.SimpleDateFormat" xmlns:srv="bla.bla.bla1" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:customCoreFunction="http://bla.bla.bla2" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:productCoreFunction="http://bla.bla.bla" xmlns:srvesb0="http://esb.original.com.br/HistoricoComentario" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xbla.bla.bla"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>  
      <xsl:variable name="uriTokenSeparator" select="';'"/>  
      <xsl:variable name="uriKeyValueSeparator" select="'='"/>  
      <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:variable name="messageContext" select="."/>  
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
          <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>  
          <soapenv:Body> 
            <xsl:element name="srvesb0:getHistory"> 
              <xsl:if test="((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId) and ((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId!='') or (/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId/@*)))"> 
                <xsl:element name="srvesb0:idCapture"> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId"/> 
                </xsl:element> 
              </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:element> 
          </soapenv:Body> 
        </soapenv:Envelope> 
      </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to get only the code inside the 'Body' tag:

```
<soapenv:Body> 
            <xsl:element name="srvesb0:getHistory"> 
              <xsl:if test="((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId) and ((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId!='') or (/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId/@*)))"> 
                <xsl:element name="srvesb0:idCapture"> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId"/> 
                </xsl:element> 
              </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:element> 
          </soapenv:Body>
```

then, iterate element by element and get it's atributes.

but any search codes that I use works 
.xpath
.iter
.find

if I iterate the .getroot() the result appear:

```
    import lxml.etree as XT


xslt = XT.parse('transformation.xsl')
rootxslt = xslt.getroot()

for child in rootxslt:
    child.tag = child.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
    print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text
    for child2 in child:
        child2.tag = child2.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
        print child2.tag, child2.attrib, child2.text
        for child3 in child2:
            child3.tag = child3.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
            print child3.tag, child3.text, child3.text
            for child4 in child3:
                child4.tag = child4.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
                print child4.tag, child4.text, child4.text
                for child5 in child4:
                    child5.tag = child5.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
                    print child5.tag, child5.text, child5.text
```

But if a try to iterate a specific tag, any result appear:

```
    import lxml.etree as XT


xslt = XT.parse('transformation.xsl')
rootxslt = xslt.getroot()

for child in rootxslt.findall("Body"):
    child.tag = child.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
    print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text
    for child2 in child:
        child2.tag = child2.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
        print child2.tag, child2.attrib, child2.text
        for child3 in child2:
            child3.tag = child3.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
            print child3.tag, child3.text, child3.text
            for child4 in child3:
                child4.tag = child4.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
                print child4.tag, child4.text, child4.text
                for child5 in child4:
                    child5.tag = child5.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
                    print child5.tag, child5.text, child5.text
```

Someone know how can I get the tree from the 'Body' tag?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `xpath` method to do this.

```
>>> import lxml.etree as XT
>>> xslt = XT.parse('c:/scratch/sample.xml')
>>> xslt.xpath('.//soapenv:Body', namespaces={'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'})
[<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body at 0x5e60c88>]
>>> theBody[0]
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body at 0x5e60c88>
>>> list(theBody[0].iterdescendants())
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}element at 0x5e60b08>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}if at 0x5e7ea08>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}element at 0x5e7ea48>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}value-of at 0x5e7ea88>]
```

Once you locate the container for the code you want, as shown here you can iterate through the container's descendants.

EDIT: Another approach.

Assumptions: (1) That the one namespace will work for a variety of `xsl` documents, as shown in the following code. (2) That an `xsl:variable` `messageContext` will immediately precede any content you want.

Then begin by finding the `messageContext` element preceding that content. Now find the element next to this. Finally, iterate through the descendants of the `body` of the message content. Or whatever it is that you want to do.

```
>>> import lxml.etree as XT
>>> xslt = XT.parse('sample.xml')
>>> sibling = xslt.xpath('.//xsl:variable[@name="messageContext"]', namespaces={'xsl': "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"})
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at 0x11912c8>
>>> envelope = sibling[0].getnext()
>>> list(envelope.iter())
[<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at 0x11912c8>, <Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Header at 0x1191448>, <Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body at 0x1191248>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}element at 0x11910c8>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}if at 0x1191488>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}element at 0x11914c8>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}value-of at 0x1191508>]
```

EDIT 2: And another, using BeautifulSoup. If you use `'xml'` as the second parameter to BeautifulSoup then you can readily parse namespaced elements, as I've just learned from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35564127/131187.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('sample.xml').read(), 'xml')
>>> body = soup.find_all('Body')
>>> body
[<Body>
<xsl:element name="srvesb0:getHistory">
<xsl:if test="((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId) and ((/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId!='') or (/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId/@*)))">
<xsl:element name="srvesb0:idCapture">
<xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</Body>]
>>> body[0].find('value-of')
<xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/note[@name='note']/catchId"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill Bell it works! but in this way I need to set the namespace inside the code: 'namespaces={'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}', or './/soapenv:'. Is there a way to use the xpath for the tag 'Body'  ignoring the namespace before?

Comment: I regret, not that I know of.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid setting the namespace?

Comment: becouse the namespaces can change, depending on the XML used. I found something like this .//*[local-name()='NamedTag'], but it return SyntaxError: invalid predicate error

Comment: I've suggested another approach.

Comment: ... and another.

Comment: thank you. I had found BeautifulSoup before but I didn't found if BeautifulSoup works without namespaces. It works perfectly.