# Python3.X: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. A One script working other isnt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there so ive got an interesting issue. I cant get the a specific piece of information out of a document using this piece of code.

```
class IXBRL():



def __init__(self, f, raise_on_error=True):

    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "xml")

    self.raise_on_error = raise_on_error

    self.errors = []

    self._get_schema()

@classmethod

def open(cls, filename, raise_on_error=True):

    with open(filename) as a:

        return cls(a, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)


def _get_schema(self):

    resources = self.soup.find(['ix:references', 'references'])
    for s in resources.find_all(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef', 'schemaref', 'link:schemaref']):
        self.schema = s.get('xlink:href') <- Error is here.
```

I call like this:

```
x = IXBRL(a) <- a is the file
```

That returns the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

However when I run this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
filename = "F:\Test\ErrorFolder\ErrorFile.html"

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    resources = soup.find(['ix:references', 'references'])
    #print(resources)
    for s in resources.find_all(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef', 'schemaref', 'link:schemaref']):
        x = s.get('xlink:href')
        print(x)
```

Returns the correct result: https://xbrl.frc.org.uk/FRS-102/2014-09-01/FRS-102-2014-09-01.xsd

Any ideas why and how do I implement it in the above code to get it functioning.

Edit1:

Ive moved lines of code around and noticed that I get this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-16-503c3726b1af> in <module>
         50 
         51         with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as a:
    ---> 52             x = IXBRL(a)
         53             # print(x.to_table())
         54             print(json.dumps(x.to_table(), indent=4))

    ~\OneDrive\Desktop\parse-master\parse\core.py in __init__(self, f, raise_on_error)
         21         self.errors = []
         22 
    ---> 23         self._get_schema()
         24 
         25         self._get_contexts()

    ~\OneDrive\Desktop\parse-master\parse\core.py in _get_schema(self)
         47         self.schema = self.soup.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef', 'schemaref', 'link:schemaref']).get('xlink:href')
         48         self.namespaces = {}
    ---> 49 
         50         for k in self.soup.find('html').attrs:
         51             if k.startswith("xmlns") or ":" in k:

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This now makes me wonder if the error is actually on line 23.

Comment: Have you tried making fewer changes between the two? For example in the working example BS gets the file itself and "html.parser", in the broken one it gets the file content and "xml". Also that doesn't seem like it should be a class anyway, see https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html

Comment: I think the answer on this question may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680303/beautifulsoup-find-all-method-not-working-with-namespaced-tags 

I believe that BS is not namespace aware.  Your code seems to be trying both `link:schemaRef` and `schemaRef`, but the namespace prefix could be anything, as what matters is what the prefix is bound to.  If you're parsing namespaced XML, you should use a namespace-aware parser, or you're likely to write inherently fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same file both times?
I have no experience with this library but it looks like a parser mismatch to me. In the first part of the code `self.soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "xml")` opens an xml parser. If you are still using the html file it would make sense to me that it can't find any matches (since the file is not xml) and returns `None`, which leads to your error.

In the working part you use a html parser with this line `soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')`.

Comment: Yes I am using the same file both times. Ill try that thank you for your suggestion

Comment: It looks like the file being parsed is Inline XBRL ([iXBRL](http://www.xbrl.org/ixbrl)), in which case it is XHTML which is XML ([Inline XBRL Specification](http://www.xbrl.org/specification/inlinexbrl-part1/rec-2013-11-18/inlinexbrl-part1-rec-2013-11-18.html)).

Comment: After some deeper burrowing. What I have noticed is that the for documents that do work the string being searched for looks like this: 

<link:schemaRef xlink:href="https://xbrl.frc.org.uk/FRS-102/2014-09-01/FRS-102-2014-09-01.xsd" xlink:type="simple" />  

and the strings that are causing the issue look like this:

<link:schemaRef xlink:href="https://xbrl.frc.org.uk/FRS-102/2014-09-01/FRS-102-2014-09-01.xsd" xlink:type="simple" xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"></link:schemaRef> Might it because schemaRef appears twice its cant read it properly because its a find not a find_all?